# How to access Acomba database by SDK and PHP

Tags: php, database, sdk

I'm running an apache server on my machine (localhost) and I'm trying to connect to the Acomba database by the SDK with PHP...

I have the login and the password (for the demo) but I don't have a CLUE how to proceed. Online and on the documetation, they don't help alot .. so I'm trying with you guyz if you already do something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it in asp.net... There is the code, if this can help anyone.

```
Sub ConnectionUser()
    Dim AcoSDKInt
    Set AcoSDKInt = Server.CreateObject("AcoSDK.AcoSDKX")
    Dim Acomba
    Set Acomba = Server.CreateObject("AcoSDK.AcombaX")
    Dim UserInt
    Set UserInt = Server.CreateObject("AcoSDK.User")
    Dim Version
    Dim CompanyPath
    Dim AcombaPath
    Dim MotDePasse
    Dim Exist
    Dim Error
    Version = AcoSDKInt.VaVersionSDK
    Error = AcoSDKInt.Start(Version)
    If Error = 0 Then     
    CompanyPath = "C:\F1000.dta\DemoSDK_FR"
    AcombaPath = "C:\Aco_SDK"
    MotDePasse = "DEMO"
    Exist = Acomba.CompanyExists(CompanyPath)
    If Exist <> 0 Then
    Error = Acomba.OpenCompany(AcombaPath, CompanyPath)
    If Error = 0 Then
    UserInt.PKey_UsNumber = "Supervisor"
    Error = UserInt.FindKey(1, False)
    If Error = 0 Then
    Error = Acomba.LogCurrentUser(UserInt.Key_UsCardPos, MotDePasse)
    If Error = 0 Then
    'response.write("Connexion de l'usager complétée avec succès.")
    Else
    'response.write("Erreur: " & Acomba.GetErrorMessage(Error))
    End If
    Else
    'response.write("Erreur: " & Acomba.GetErrorMessage(Error))
    End If
    Else
    'response.write("Erreur: " & Acomba.GetErrorMessage(Error))
    End If
    Else
    'response.write("Dossier de la société invalide")
    End If   
    Else
    'response.write("Erreur: " & Acomba.GetErrorMessage(Error))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What "Error=0" and "Error<>0" actually mean, exactly in your if statements?

Comment: If Error = 0 mean "success"